# Magento 2: wrong permission generate in generated folder

Tags: magento2

when i execute setup:upgrade command then some file is generated in generated/ folder. 
after i have execute `chmod -R 777 /generated` command
but when i check in some admin page like : Product grid page then it will showing below error :

```
Class Magento\Catalog\Model\View\Asset\ImageFactory does not exist
```

so i need to go into this directory

```
generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/View/Asset
```

and when i check this folder permission then it will showing 775 so i need to change permission 777 into `Asset` folder so then it will working fine.

so what is solution to every time update folder permission ?
any idea please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't give 777 permission as it is not recommended. Try these commands

```
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
sudo chown -R :<web server group> .
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

`chmod g+w` gives write permission to the group owner for those directories. `chmod g+ws` sets up the group id to the directory where all new files and created in that directory inherit the group id of the parent directory.

So after running the `setup:upgrade` command, have you run the `setup:static-content:deploy` command, as running setup upgrade will clean the file system such cache, generated and static files

Comment: i have use ec2 aws serevr so is that okay with your command ?

Comment: what is do chmod g+w {} + & chmod g+ws {} +.

Comment: chmod g+w {} gives write permission to the group owner whereas g+ws {} is write permission to the group owner in strict mode to set user id or group id. You can find more details here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html So you are giving write access to the group owner for the following directories

Answer (score 1):

You can use 777 (all permission) but it's not secured on server, it's fine with localhost only:

```
chmod -R 777 generated
```

When using server you can give permission to specific user group using below commands:

```
chown -R username:groupname generated
```

NOTE: Go to magento root directory for using these commands.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `chmod -R 777 /generated` use `chmod -R 777 generated`

as `/generate` represent that your generate directory is at your server root directory

Answer (score 0):

You can Give All read and write permission to you generated Folder By

```
chmod +rwx generated
```